# lilypondfile in macro, with filename as argument

Tags: macros, lilypond

I want to write a simple tunebook, with a different tune on each page.
I'm writing the tunes with lilypond.

In order to make things easier, I want to write a macro that manages the layout of each page (title, short text, music score). Inside this macro I would need a

```
\lily{path_to_score}
```

where path_to_score is a variable (needs to change for each new page).

I tried defining a macro

```
\newcommand{\lily}[1]{
\lilypondfile[quote,noindent]{#1}
}
```

but compilation fails after

```
lilypond-book: error: file not found: #1
```

Compilation is done with

```
lilypond-book --output=outputs --pdf MAIN.lytex
cd outputs
pdflatex -output-directory ../ MAIN.tex
```

as recommended by the documentation.

I have looked into `expandafter` ideas but really not sure about how that works.

Any help is welcome, I started working with Lilypond-book yesterday so totally new in the field.

Cheers !

Comment: Welcome! As far as I can see, the `lilypond-book` preprocessor *needs* to see `\lilypondfile` explicitly: it doesn't process TeX macros.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that would be the answer... It makes sense because of the multiple step processing (first lilypond, then latex), but it was worth asking.
Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The program **lilypond-book** processes your input-file which has the extension ".lytex":
The program **lilypond-book** builds a new file with the extension ".tex".
The file with the extension ".tex" in turn is processed/compiled by the **LaTeX-compiler** and a pdf-file is created.

The program **lilypond-book** extracts from your .lytex input file the contents of the `\begin{lilypond}..\end{lilypond}` environments and the `\lilypond{..}`-commands and the `\lilypondfile{...}`-commands and the `\musicxmlfile{...}`-commands, and in turn calls the **lilypond** program for each extracted thing to generate from it a graphic file from which the corresponding set of musical notes can be displayed.
In addition, the **lilypond-book** program crafts a .tex file with the contents of your .lytex input file, but instead of `\begin{lilypond}..\end{lilypond}`-environments and instead of `\lilypond`-/`\lilypondfile`-/`\musicxmlfile`-commands, the .tex-file contains instructions to include these graphic files/.pdf files.

So the thing is this:

`\begin{lilypond}..\end{lilypond}` environments and `\lilypond`-/`\lilypondfile`-/`\musicxmlfile`-commands are instructions directed to the **lilypond-book** program.
The **LaTeX compiler** does not understand these instructions.
The **LaTeX-compiler** does not need to, because when the **LaTeX-compiler** comes into play, the program **lilypond-book** has already replaced these instructions in the .tex file with instructions that the **LaTeX-compiler** understands.

Vice versa, the **lilypond-book** program does not understand LaTeX commands. It doesn't need to understand them, because they will be processed later by the **LaTeX-compiler**.

In your scenario, however, you want the program **lilypond-book** to understand a LaTeX macro, namely the LaTeX macro `\lily`.

This does not work.
**lilypond-book** stubbornly searches for `\begin{lilypond}..\end{lilypond}` environments and `\lilypond`-/`\lilypondfile`-/`\musicxmlfile`-commands without interpreting or executing surrounding LaTeX code.

If the .lytex input file says

```
\newcommand{\lily}[1]{%
  \lilypondfile[quote,noindent]{#1}
}%
```

, then the program **lilypond-book** reacts only to the phrase `\lilypondfile[quote,noindent]{#1}` and "thinks" that an `\includegraphics{<graphics file>}`-command shall be inserted into the .tex-file it creates for the **LaTeX-compiler**, and that the **lilypond** program shall be called for processing a lilypond-file literally named **#1** in order to generate the corresponding graphics file.

A file with the name **#1** does not exist. So **lilypond-book** returns an error message.

---

The LaTeX-package [lyLuaTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/lyluatex) provides means for invoking **lilypond** directly during latex-compilation. Probably using the package [lyLuaTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/lyluatex) instead of **lilypond-book** is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out my Lieder-Package on [github](https://github.com/MaestroGlanz/Lieder-Package). I think, it provides everything you need.
You just would have to typeset each song first, then include it via a command. It should be even compatible with lilypond-book.

Comment: On second thought, it is only compatible, I think, if you place the songbook in the preamble and not in a separate sty-file.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Ulrich Diez, [lyluatex](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex) allows such definitions, but with some caveats you should be aware of, that are mentioned in the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf). See the "Examples" section, "Wrapping Commands" subsection (p.43 as of version 1.1.2).